# STM32: usart IAP

Tags: c, in-app-purchase, microcontroller, stm32, ota

I'm trying to use example code provided by X-CUBE-IAP-USART package to develop IAP FW for STM32L0xx device. I'm using STM32L073 Nucleo64 board for development.

When I send compiled FW using TeraTerm's YMODEM protocol nothing happens.

Only thing that is being send to target STM device is: "ota_test.elf166988 13332031541 100644¶Ê" over and over again. When I debugged example code I was getting HAL_TIMEOUT on receive. (rework example code to work with interrupts?). I've triple checked my USART settings so that is not the problem. Cam anyone please help me or send some functioning example code please? Original example code was written for STM32L073 eval board, but I've ported it to work with NUCLEO board, maybe I've made mistake there but, I've configured all peripherals exactly as they were configured in example code.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is programming via YMODEM the normal thing to do for this dev board?

Comment: the code provided in package i downloaded from ST website uses this protocol. It is only software implementation of YMODEM so HW shouldn't affect it. And YMODEM is sending 1kB packets of data that is automatically written to flash, because sending whole compiled firmware file may require external flash to store before wtiting on to STM32 internal flash

Comment: And you think that STM builtin bootloader does not have its own protocol? You receive some header with the informations for the bootloader. It does not work like this (1k packets and it saves). Read the APnotes carefully.

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach for firmware update over bluetooth. My BT module uses USART to communicate witch microprocessor. But firstly I'm testing just with PC connected to microprocessor using USART.

Comment: Read the documentation - try to understand how it works. Then try to do your own stuff. It is not as easy as you think. Voting to close.

Comment: Application notes are much comprehensive, I'm trying to understand the code. My biggest problem now is that microprocessor is not receiving any of the data send by PC.

Comment: So what you want to write - the custom bootloader? If yes - share your code.

Comment: No, no custom bootloader. Example provided by ST simply receives file and writes it to microprocessor flash and then jumps to address where it was written (executing uploaded firmware) I want to be able to upload new versions of firmware to my device using bluetooth (as I mentioned bluetooth module on my device is communicating with microprocessor using USART).

Comment: https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-iap-usart.html
My code is basically only the example that you can download in this link. I did not modified it. Sorry if i was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am using STM32L476 and faced same issues while writing boodloader for my project.
The problems I encountered are:

- HAL_UART_Receive() not working properly, always returning HAL_TIMEOUT
- After the uart problem was solved, I was still not be able to upload bin files. Where I noticed that the codes were trying to delete the wrong memory address.

Applied solutions:

- I changed the usart conection options. I used DMA channel to receive ymodem packages.
- In the FLASH_If_Erase() function, pEraseInit.Banks configured 'FLASH_BANK_1' instead of 'FLASH_BANK_2'. I guess this was a bug and needs to be updated by ST developers.

I added the bootloader projects link where you can find all codes and the changes. Hope it helps with your problems.

Link : https://github.com/yelkovany/Embedded_codes.git